# Correspondence between first homology group and deck transformations.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $M$ be a connected topological manifold with universal covering $\pi: \widetilde{M} \rightarrow M$ and let
$p \in \widetilde{M}$ be a point.

Let $\alpha,\beta : \widetilde{M} \rightarrow \widetilde{M}$ be two deck transformations.

Let $\gamma_1 \subset \widetilde{M}$ be a path connecting $p$ and $\alpha \circ \beta(p)$
and let $\gamma_2 \subset \widetilde{M}$ be a path connecting $p$ and $\beta \circ \alpha(p)$.

**My question is:** is the homology class of the loop $\pi \circ \gamma_1$ the same as the
homology class of the loop $\pi \circ \gamma_2$ in $M$. I have the feeling that this should be false for the classes in the fundamental group and is connected the the homology group being abelian.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you know the correspondence between automorphisms of the universal cover and the fundamental group? Hurewicz theorem?